# What's the cfscript equivalent to <cfobjectcache action="clear">?

Tags: coldfusion

I pretty sure that coldfusion hasn't got a cfscript alternative for the `<cfobjectcache>` tag, but I was wondering if I can do the same as `<cfobjectcache action="clear">` in cfscript. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ObjectCacheTag on `action="clear"` calls purgeQueryCache() on the DataSourceService, exposed from the ServiceFactory.

```
<cfscript>
createObject('java','coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory').getDataSourceService().purgeQueryCache();
</cfscript>
```

This is how it works in CF8, CF9 and CF10

Comment: Does not seem to work in CF11. But you can use `cacheRemoveAll('query')`

Answer (score 3):

no such thing, just call an UDF that's written in CFML that calls `<cfobjectcache action="clear">`

update: `CacheRemoveAll()` in CF10 might do what you need. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSaff1f2a7b564e360784fa97f13510d891d7-8000.html